# What is the most robust way to deal with errors or unexpected results in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

So when I've always used

```
die($someErrorMessage);
```

in all my PHP code until now, but I don't want to stop the entire script because one thing went wrong. If a function can't complete the page should still be able to load normally but with something informing the user that **something** went wrong.

I thought about just returning null in the catch block, but wanted to know if there is any standard method to handling an exception in PHP so that it doesn't stop the page generating, but it returns something useful.

Comment: Browse this list for ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error-handling+php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED AFTER RE- READING THE QUESTION:

Best way to probably go about this is using an if statement to check

```
if($error_exists) {
 // echo error or call error function
} else {
 // echo clean stuff or call function
}
```

That's the way I generally handle most error's is just using an if statement or if you are looking to do like a mysql_connect you can use a try/catch function

```
 try {
   // some code
 } catch($error)
   // report error
 }
```

Comment: I'm seeing the question in full now, I'm sorry, didn't realize this was meant for production. But yeah, your right, it's a bad idea if your not using it for debugging. 

And die() is actually a really good method, but it'll stop the script completely. the best way honestly is a if statement. I'm gonna modify the above answer, look at it